# Set ng-model for dropdown which generated from dictionary in Angular

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, dictionary

I have dropdown which retrieve data from Dictionary(int,string):

```
<select 
    class="form-control" 
    data-ng-model="model.Case.OwnerUserId" 
    data-ng-options="key as value for (key,value) in model.OwnerUsers" >
</select>
```

`model.Case.OwnerUserId` is `int` value which i try to bind by `ng-model` directive and set selected value for dropdown.But dropdown left unselected. What i do wrong in this situation?

UPDATE: Part of view models data

```
public class CaseViewModel
{
    public Case Case { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<int,string> Facilities { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<int, string> OwnerUsers { get; set; }
}

public class Case
{
    public int CaseId { get; set; }

    public int ResidentId { get; set; }

    public int OwnerUserId { get; set; } ...
```

Sample of JS Model after serialize:

```
{
"Case": {
    "CaseId": 27,
    "ResidentId": 4478,
    "OwnerUserId": 15,
    "CreatedByUserId": 20,
    "LastUpdatedUserId": null,
    "ReceivedDate": "2014-06-23T12:49:54.713", ...


"OwnerUsers": {
    "35": "a.markov",
    "15": "a.zaharov",
    "20": "e.martynov",
    "36": "a.oryel",
    "40": "test01"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your model? Not with the real data but still with the properties you're describing above.

Comment: I meant the js/JSON object that angular works with, not the `.net` backend. Something to test your angular  code against.

Comment: What's the browser's network say? What data is sent to the the angular model?

Comment: Ok. but i use simple jQuery.parseJSON($("#modelData").val()) and model data is get from hidden field with value Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))

Comment: Nevermind just give me an example, so that I can carry on. I must somehow test your example with the structure of your model.
Give me the result of `console.log( jQuery.parseJSON($("#modelData").val()) )`

Comment: Added part of js model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

`data-ng-options="key for (key , value) in mymodel.Case.OwnerUsers"`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g8Xtp/

Comment: "in" instead of "is"

Answer (score 0):

try the following if you want to include both Value and Description

```
key as value for (key , value) in CONTROLLER.DICTIONARY
```