# How to bind C# dictionary to the dropdown list in angular 6 material

Tags: c#, angular, angular-material

I used C# dictionary as follows in my model class

```
 public class CommonInfo
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> JobTypes { get { return _dic; } set { _dic = value; } }

    Dictionary<string, string> _dic = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"PO","Production" },
        {"SO", "Sales" },
        {"PS", "Production and Sales" }
    };
}
```

then I need to bind this dictionary value to my dropdown list in Angular 6 Material

```
this.jobTypeList = currentDefaults.JobTypes;
```

and ui

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Job type</mat-label>
    <mat-select>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let jobtype of jobTypeList" [value]="jobtype.value"> {{jobtype.id}}
      </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: have you looked into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406849/set-ng-model-for-dropdown-which-generated-from-dictionary-in-angular

Comment: is that worked for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a suitable answer to solve this case.
we can convert the object to an array as follows

```
Object.keys(jobTypeObj).map(key => ({ type: key, value: jobTypeObj[key] }));
```

Then it can easy to bind the dropdown.
I think this will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Dictornary is nothing but key value pair , so you can map your serverside reponse to typescript model which as below

```
export interface KeyValue {
  key?: string;
  value?: string;
}
```

call to serverside method is

```
  geJobTypes(): Observable<KeyValue[]> {
    const url = `service/jobtypes`;
    //httpclient to make call to server method 
    return this.apiHandler.get<KeyValue[]>(url);
  }
```

html is

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let jobtype of jobTypeList" [value]="jobtype.value"> {{jobtype.key}}
      </mat-option>
```

in C# do like this

```
public  IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>  GetJobTypes(){
_dic.ToList<KeyValuePair<double, double>>();
}
```